# What's the most appropriate equivalent of the Section element in Open-XML?

Tags: c#, wpf, openxml, wordml

I'm trying to convert a document formatted in xaml to a `WordProcessingML` document, I'm wondering what is the most appropriate WordProcessingML element to replace a `Section` element (in XAML) with it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally it seems that I need to use the table `w:tbl`.